# SQL Column truncation to new Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any simple way to copy data from one table to another, which both have the same column names, but the first table is all varchar(max), and the second table is all different values ie varchar(12), varchar(50), etc.  Can I simply allow truncation somehow?  Or will I have to specify every size, using a left truncate for each?

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use ? (as there can be specific solutions)

Comment: @JérômeRadix Not sure I understand the question fully.  It's SQL server 2008 R2.  Is there a more specific answer I can provide?

Comment: It's exactly what I've asked. I add the sqlserver tag to the question.

Comment: @Timotheus that is THE question, and you answered it. For future reference, that information is important to giving you an accurate answer in most cases. There are some universal aspects to SQL as a language, then there are implementation-specific quirks, gotchyas, and additions to the language, so the RDBMS is crucial to know. Further, your question is also related to the storage an row mechanics, which are going to be vastly different from one RDBMS to another.

Answer (score 1):

As [said by the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190368.aspx), you could silently truncate values with `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`:

```
1> SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF      
2> go                         
1> create table table1 (col1 varchar(100));
2> go
1> insert into table1 (col1) values ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
2> go

(1 rows affected)
1> select * from table1;
2> go
col1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

(1 rows affected)
1> create table table2 (col1 char(10));
2> go
1> insert into table2 select * from table1;
2> go

(1 rows affected)
1> select * from table2;
2> go
col1
----------
abcdefghij
```

Tested on :

```
1> select @@version;
2> go


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64)
        Oct 19 2012 13:38:57
        Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
        Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

But the documentation says :

> Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 through current version),
>   Azure SQL Database.

Comment: This was great for getting it into a table exactly like the other table (I didn't want to insert to the actual table yet for fear of something messing up), but then when I tried to do the insert into the actual table, I got a "INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns...<etc>"  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply insert from the first table into the second as long as the data in each column in the first table does not exceed the specified column lengths in the second table. You will only need use conversion if the types are different in the second table. assuming MSSQL

Comment: But some of them do exceed the length, which is why I made the varchar(max) table in the first place, my java code was having issues with the specific sizes, so I made a new table to get the data into, until I had time to figure out where the too big line was (there are over 100 columns, and it's a hard thing to track down since the error gives no information about where it's happening!)

Comment: Ah so actually your question should be how can I find the maximum lengths of the text stored in each column in a given database table.

Answer (score 0):

You could also CAST each column you wish to insert (in the select part of the insert) which will enforce truncation as shown by:

```
SELECT CAST('12345' AS VARCHAR(3))
```